# How can I use eval in navigeteurl?

Tags: asp.net

```
NavigateUrl="<%$ RouteUrl:RouteName=Kurumsal, ModulBaslik=<%# Eval("ModulResim")%>%>"
```

How use to eval in navigateurl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`GetRouteUrl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.control.getrouteurl) as follow:

```
NavigateUrl='<%# GetRouteUrl("Kurumsal", new {ModulBaslik= Eval("ModulResim")}) %>' >
```

Comment: Thanks. Türkün Türkten başka dostu yok. :)) çok teşekkürler